# Why nuxt insert all css link into every page with extractCss true

Tags: html, css, nuxt.js

```
build: {
  postcss:{
    preset:{
      autoprefixer:{
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      }
    }
  },
extractCSS: true
}
```

After run build and run start. I got a page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/407741cd4bb24a8e4f04.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/6aaf03451f16601ceda4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/6f1ab227fd9711991740.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/7bb339c094c38df1b4df.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/ab6e091c52a8bc8cfdda.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/c931fb170d5cdc1f7247.css">
```

The first css is base.css, the second css is element-ui, but the remaining 4 files is wrong. Because I have 4 pages. Page should only have its own css file and 2 common css file, but they hava all.
How can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it, nuxt@2.0.0 have this problem, update to 2.3.4 will fix it.